# typescript get a value from a json object map using a variable key

Tags: typescript, dictionary

I am having trouble trying to get a a value from a map where we variablize the key.

Let me show what I am trying to achieve.
lets say I have a variable map with the values:

```
let map = {
 Argentina : "222",
 Brazil : "333",
 Mexico : "444",
};
```

and I have a user input variable country

```
let country = "Argentina";
```

I would like to use the two as follows to use the user inputted key value to get value from the map.

```
console.log(map[$country]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few ways of doing what you want (probably there is a few more):

```ts
let map = {
 Argentina : "222",
 Brazil : "333",
 Mexico : "444",
};

let country = "Argentina";
let country2: keyof typeof map = "Argentina";
// let country3: keyof typeof map = "Argentina2"; // Type '"Argentina2"' is not assignable to type '"Argentina" | "Brazil" | "Mexico"'.

console.log(map[country as keyof typeof map]);
console.log((map as any)[country]);
console.log(map[country2]);
```

Playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.4#code/DYUwLgBAtghgDhAvBA3gKAgQQE4HMQB2YAlgTBAFwQBEATPdQDQYBC2MAXscJTQMwCmGALIgAHsQDGAe17UALIqEBfANxo0oSDICuRbAE8kNHPiKkY1dVoi79B2lQDWIA9IBmEMAbggP0eGNqU0ISMis0AHpIiBs7MEM+Z1d-b19-WARkYLxQi1orCGiIABUfEAgAchyzMJgCyohiAGcIAmlIGGbm4lwyACNQL1k0iuqQ83CIAB8aNk5uahmaUQkZakqAOg0ZAmbpUE3gaVwACkyAbXjDCC6IFzdPUYz4AF0ASnVd-cPjs-PAncYAQDO8rtI9AkDB8vtI9gcQEcTgC4ODIYZaDCgA)

Another approach would be to specify a type (which will be less strict) for `map` object explicitly

```ts
// let map: {[key: string]: string} = {
let map: {[key: string]: any} = {
 Argentina : "222",
 Brazil : "333",
 Mexico : "444",
};

let country = "Argentina";
console.log(map[country]);
```

Playgrond [link2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.4#code/PTAEBsFMBdQWwIYAcBcoDeBtA1pAnmgM7QBOAlgHYDmAukaZVQL6gC8GAUFLIqhjvnrlqdUAgp4W7dB1ABBElUgVolBKDQAiAEy7NAGlkAhEggBeZcBtCaAzPYOyAspAAeZAMYB7a5oAsAY5MANwcXDCg3gCuKiR4bDYKSipqmqHeFIReUAB04F5UABS8mNGxeDQAlMFAA)

Comment: The second approach works when the country is a user input or else it complains about the assignability. thanks!

Comment: @ShakyaS You can also use something like `let country = prompt("Enter the name") as keyof typeof map;`. [link3](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.4&ssl=8&ssc=60&pln=8&pc=1#code/PTAEBsFMBdQWwIYAcBcoDeBtA1pAnmgM7QBOAlgHYDmAukaZVQL6gC8GAUFLIqhjvnrlqdUAgp4W7dB1ABBElUgVolBKDQAiAEy7NAGlkAhEggBeZcBtCaAzPYOyAspAAeZAMYB7a5oAsAY5MANwcXDCg3gCuKiR4bKBIJF5wSNAAFJoAoiqQJKDQABaQoBQIcJCaAJRihKC4eF4AZgV4SJDN8Mih3hSEXlAAdOBeVOm8mNGxeDRVwUA). Anyway, im glad it worked for you.